# how to navigate from one view to next in a JSF2/JPA/stateless EBJs (jsf managed controllers) and retain data

Tags: jpa, view, jsf-2, ejb, stateless

I have a web app using JSF2 with JPA Entities, Stateless ejb session beans as my facade/ejb objects, and managed beans (request and view scoped) as controllers exposing business methods, managed controllers are pulling data from the injected stateless session beans.

but i am confused how to navigate and retain data accross views in my controllers in this environment, for example:

I have a jsf2 view page (departmentView.xhtml)  that displays a list of Department objects and each row has an edit item. Clicking edit I want to load a new page and display 
a list or Employee's for that department on the new page, so i invoke the Employee controller passing it the selected Department

```
action="#{employeeController.getEmployeeListForADepartment(ithDepartment)}"
```

here is a snippet of my departmentView.xhtml

```
    <h:dataTable id="table" value="#{departmentController.departmentList}" 
            var="ithDepartment">
...
<h:column>              
<h:commandLink id="editId" value="Edit"
action="#{employeeController.getEmployeeListForADepartment(ithDepartment)}" />
</h:column>
```

and my employeeController is defined as

```
ManagedBean(name = "employeeController")
@ViewScoped
public class EmployeeController implements Serializable {
   ...
private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   ...      

@EJB
private com.ejb.session.EmployeeFacade ejbEmployeeFacade;    
   ...

public List<Employee> getEmployeeListForADepartment(Department dept) 
{
    if(employeeList==null || employeeList.isEmpty())
          employeeList = ejbEmployeeFacade.findEmployeesByDepartment(dept);  

// now i want to navigate to the employee view showing these employees for the
// selected department.
// but this navigation below triggers creating a new EmployeeController 
// and i lose my employeeList 
    return "employeeView";
}
```

i really want to avoid using jsf session scope, and believe there is a way to do this, just not reading about it in any of my jsf/ejb books.

thinking outloud, maybe don't have `EmployeeController.getEmployeeListForADepartment(..)` do a lookup, just create a parameter from the department id and pass that along via `return "employeeView?departmentId=X";` and have constructor then do a lookup if the id is present?

can somehelp me with the proper way to implement this in EJB/JSF2 environment

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple GET `<h:link>` in the source view to pass the department ID and a `<f:viewParam>` in the target view to convert and set the department.

E.g.

```
<h:link id="editId" value="Edit" outcome="employeeView">
    <f:param name="departmentId" value="#{ithDepartment.id}" />
</h:link>
```

with

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{editDepartmentBean.department}"
        converter="#{departmentConverter}" converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown department."
        required="true" requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system." />
</f:metadata>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EditDepartmentBean {

    private Department department;

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: one further clarification, I can navigate to the same 'list of employees' view/page in 2 senerios, 1) I have a department id and consequently only display employees for that dept id and 2) if i do not have a department id (no previous selection from department view) so i would want to display all employees from all departments. I assume i could just remove the sample attribute `required="true"` above and then my EmployeeController would look to see if a department id has been set and either return 1) a list of employees for a deptartment  or 2) all employees from all departments?

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Remove the `required="true"` and add an `<f:event type="preRenderView">` which handles loading of employee list accordingly.

Comment: 3 comments in case it helps anyone 1) if I put the original code's EmployeeController scope to `@RequestScoped` instead of the `@ViewScoped`, then i retain data the when going from departmentView.xhtml to employeeView.xhtml, makes total JSF sense. 2) Implementing that way causes a POST to occur, cause implemented with `<h:commandLink .. value="Edit" />` 3) BalusC way is better because it adhears to a RESTful design, does GET not POST -> less data xferred, and is bookmarkable, i.e. http://../employeeView.jsf?deptantmentId=1. BalusC, thanks for being great community member. Merry Christmas!